# Why is the following operation allowed: $X I - P^{-1} A P = P^{-1} (XI-A) P$

Tags: linear-algebra

$X I - P^{-1}  A P = P^{-1} (XI-A) P$

Where A is a diagonalizable matrix. Is it because $XI-A$ only changes the row of A and thus is still similar to A? But I'm confused because what is the exact operation that we are allowed to do then to move the $P^{-1}$. And also $XI - A \neq A$.

I hope someone can clear this up. thanks in advance.

Comment: Notice that $I=P^{-1}P$.

Comment: Presumably $X$ is a scalar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $X$ is scalar, since matrix multiplication is distributive, we have

$$P^{-1}(XI-A)P=P^{-1}XIP-P^{-1}AP=XP^{-1}P-P^{-1}AP=XI-P^{-1}AP.$$

Comment: Ah thanks that makes sense! I didn't distribute the matrices properly inside the brackets.

Why can you do this: $ P^{-1}X = XP^{-1}$? Because of that X is a diagonal matrix?

Comment: @bananenheld Matrices do not commute in general. I assumed $X$ was scalar

Comment: yeah X is supposed to be scalar, ah thanks